# Opencl with jocl: same computation rules for cpu and gpu

Tags: java, opencl, ieee-754, jocl

I'm using jocl to apply some trigonometric functions on elements of a float-array. While doing same code on both cpu and gpu at the same time, results vary minorly on the 0.000x digits and it is rarely. This must be origineated from the differecies cores of cpu/gpu. One is using a little different algorithm(maybe I'm mistaken).

Question: How can I tell opencl/jocl to use the same rounding/IEEE-rules to calculate trigonometric/exponential functions?

Edit: Could it be a System.out.println() 's rounding incident when written on console? Problem emerges especialy when applied for sin() or cos() for 80000 times of the feedback.

Thanks.

Host: fx8150 Devices: fx8150 + hd7870(will be used on 2x Xeons and 1 firegl 4800 later)

Comment: hmm tough question.. i don't know the hd7870, does it have in the specs regarding precision of the trigonometric functions? i am assuming you are computing in single-precision float. are you doing other calculation too or just sin/cos? what you mean difference between cpu/gpu? the same opencl kernel once running on CPU then running on GPU makes the difference? or GPU vs java calculated sin/cos?

Comment: Its kernel calculated by opencl in java wrapper jocl. For example on cpu result is 34.003 but gpu result is 34.00295 this is very rare in a 8192-element float array. Yes single precision for now.

Comment: hmm but why not give the same number of digits in both cases? the relative error seems (34.003-34.00295)/34.003 = 1.4E-6 somewhat greater than machine epsilon (1.1e-7). i don't know enough about float to say why. can you find for which argument x do you get sin(x) the above value, and try compute the same thing in double precision to see which one is closer to the double result?

Comment: Suspecting also the output method "System.out.println()" for this. I cannot imagine why cpu or gpu gives different results. They must obey same rules but this difference is very rare.

Comment: My brief accuracy experiments on opencl trig functions show impressive results. The OpenCL 1.2 spec allows up to 4 ULP for the sine and cosine functions. A couple of spot checks using difficult arguments resulted in zero ULP error. For single precision (type float), a 4 ULP error in sin/cos should still leave 6 good decimal digits in the fraction. You are finding cases where inly 3 fraction digits are correct. Could this be the result of accumulated error? Functions native_sin and native_cos will differ between GPU and CPU on many systems.

Comment: (... continued) While the 4 ULP limit for sin and cos do not guarantee the same result from GPU and CPU, my brief tests comparing AMD HD 7850 to AMD A6 processor show identical, zero ULP error results. Can you isolate a difference to a single argument and post it? Printing the float argument as hex is best. For example, printf ("cos (%X) = %X\n", *(uint32_t *)inputData, *(uint32_t *)outputData);

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is accumulated error through thousands of sins on a feedback type calculation. Thanks. It gets more n more when increased the loop limit. So, I'm safe at least for 3 digits after float-point  ?

Comment: you are mentioning System.out.println. But aren't you displaying the numbers in both cases by the same method?

Comment: Yes, same method. Then That must be architectural differencies of cpu and gpu.

Comment: I found something called FP_CONFIG it has things about CL_FP_CORRECTLY_ROUNDED_DIVIDE_SQRT and CL_FP_ROUND_TO_NEAREST parameters. Working on it.

Comment: In my experience, iterative algorithms using large amounts of trigonometric, power, and other intrinsic math functions can produce large differences between CPU and GPU architectures (even more than the 1E-4 error you're seeing). This is particularly noticeable if you're dealing with very large or very small floating point values. I would guess that the errors you're seeing are not going to be fixable. If you require greater numerical accuracy, you could try using double floating-point or redesigning your code.